# Ubuntu 23.04: clang++ no longer works after an upgrade

Tags: c++, clang++

Since the last update on ubuntu 23 i can't use clang++ (clang still works). Here I have tried to compile a simple empty program by activating the verbosity.

```
/tmp$ echo "int main() { return 0; }" > main.cpp && clang++ -v main.cpp
Ubuntu clang version 15.0.7
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/lib/llvm-15/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/tmp -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-15/lib/clang/15.0.7 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++ -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/backward -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-15/lib/clang/15.0.7/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/tmp -ferror-limit 19 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /tmp/main-7d807b.o -x c++ main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 15.0.7 based upon LLVM 15.0.7 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++
 /usr/lib/llvm-15/lib/clang/15.0.7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -pie --hash-style=both --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o a.out /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/llvm-15/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/main-7d807b.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/crtendS.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

There is the package list concerned by the latest upgrade on Ubuntu 23 :

```
openssh-client:amd64 (1:9.0p1-1ubuntu8.2, 1:9.0p1-1ubuntu8.4), 
python3-samba:amd64 (2:4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1, 2:4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1), 
linux-headers-generic:amd64 (6.2.0.25.25, 6.2.0.26.26), 
libldb2:amd64 (2:2.6.2+samba4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1, 2:2.6.2+samba4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1), 
libc++1-15:amd64 (1:15.0.7-3, 1:15.0.7-3ubuntu0.23.04.1), 
llvm-15-dev:amd64 (1:15.0.7-3, 1:15.0.7-3ubuntu0.23.04.1), 
linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.2.0.25.25, 6.2.0.26.26), 
libunwind-15:amd64 (1:15.0.7-3, 1:15.0.7-3ubuntu0.23.04.1), 
libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1, 2:4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1), 
libllvm15:amd64 (1:15.0.7-3, 1:15.0.7-3ubuntu0.23.04.1), 
libclang-rt-15-dev:amd64 (1:15.0.7-3, 1:15.0.7-3ubuntu0.23.04.1), 
libsmbclient:amd64 (2:4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1, 2:4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1), 
samba-dsdb-modules:amd64 (2:4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1, 2:4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1), 
linux-generic:amd64 (6.2.0.25.25, 6.2.0.26.26), 
libclang1-15:amd64 (1:15.0.7-3, 1:15.0.7-3ubuntu0.23.04.1), 
samba-common-bin:amd64 (2:4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1, 2:4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1), 
llvm-15-runtime:amd64 (1:15.0.7-3, 1:15.0.7-3ubuntu0.23.04.1), 
libclang-cpp15:amd64 (1:15.0.7-3, 1:15.0.7-3ubuntu0.23.04.1), 
llvm-15-tools:amd64 (1:15.0.7-3, 1:15.0.7-3ubuntu0.23.04.1), 
linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.2.0.25.25, 6.2.0.26.26), 
linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.2.0.25.25, 6.2.0.26.26), 
linux-image-generic:amd64 (6.2.0.25.25, 6.2.0.26.26), 
libclang-common-15-dev:amd64 (1:15.0.7-3, 1:15.0.7-3ubuntu0.23.04.1), 
python3-ldb:amd64 (2:2.6.2+samba4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1, 2:2.6.2+samba4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1), 
clang-15:amd64 (1:15.0.7-3, 1:15.0.7-3ubuntu0.23.04.1), 
smbclient:amd64 (2:4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1, 2:4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1), 
llvm-15-linker-tools:amd64 (1:15.0.7-3, 1:15.0.7-3ubuntu0.23.04.1), 
samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1, 2:4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1), 
llvm-15:amd64 (1:15.0.7-3, 1:15.0.7-3ubuntu0.23.04.1), 
samba-common:amd64 (2:4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1, 2:4.17.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1), 
google-cloud-cli:amd64 (438.0.0-0, 440.0.0-0), 
libc++abi1-15:amd64 (1:15.0.7-3, 1:15.0.7-3ubuntu0.23.04.1), 
amd64-microcode:amd64 (3.20220411.1ubuntu3, 3.20220411.1ubuntu3.1), 
linux-libc-dev:amd64 (6.2.0-25.25, 6.2.0-26.26)
```

The libstdc++ is installed, but do I have the right version?

**EDIT:**

Good idea @Basile Starynkevitch here is the output when you try to compile the same program with gcc

```
/tmp$ g++ -v -Wall main.cpp
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-12/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-12 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-12-DAPbBt/gcc-12-12.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-12-DAPbBt/gcc-12-12.3.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --enable-offload-defaulted --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.3.0 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-Wall' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a-'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE main.cpp -quiet -dumpdir a- -dumpbase main.cpp -dumpbase-ext .cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -Wall -version -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -o /tmp/ccVFOETc.s
GNU C++17 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04) version 12.3.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 12.3.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.2.0, MPC version 1.3.1, isl version isl-0.25-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/12"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/12
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/12
 /usr/include/c++/12/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++17 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04) version 12.3.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 12.3.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.2.0, MPC version 1.3.1, isl version isl-0.25-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 16d8e9c7f95d1b20c28ab711ca7df821
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-Wall' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a-'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccypmMlV.o /tmp/ccVFOETc.s
GNU assembler version 2.40 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.40
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-Wall' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a.'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccnvWVt2.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -z now -z relro /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../.. /tmp/ccypmMlV.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-Wall' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a.'
```

Comment: This sounds like a question for Ubuntu/Canonical support, rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: Try using `clang++ -v -Wall main.cpp` or `g++ -v -Wall main.cpp` to understand what the compiler is doing

Comment: I've never submitted a request to Canonical, I'm afraid it's subject to a lot of rules.

Comment: You probably mean Ubuntu 23.04. (Ubuntu version numbers are based on the month and year a version is released. There's no version 23.)